# Bash script error with strings with paths that have spaces and wildcards

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, wildcards

I am having trouble getting the basics of Bash scripting down. Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES="/home/john/my directory/*.txt"

for f in "${FILES}"
do
  echo "${f}"
done
```

All I want to do is list all the `.txt` files in a `for` loop so I can do stuff with them. But the space in the `my directory` and the asterisk in `*.txt` just aren't playing nicely. I tried using it with and without double quotes, with and without curly braces on variable names and still can't print all the `.txt` files.

This is a very basic thing, but I'm still struggling because I'm tired and can't think straight.

What am I doing wrong?

I've been able to successfully apply the script above if my FILES don't have a space or an asterisk... I had to experiment with or without the use of double quotes and braces to get it to work. But the moment I have both spaces and an asterisk, it messes everything up.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Inside quotes, the `*` will not expand to a list of files.  To use such a wildcard successfully, it must be outside of quotes.

Even if the wildcard did expand, the expression `"${FILES}"` would result in a single string, not a list of files.

One approach that would work would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/home/john/my directory/"
for f in "$DIR"/*.txt
do
  echo "${f}"
done
```

In the above, file names with spaces or other difficult characters will be handled correctly.

A more advanced approach could use bash arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=("/home/john/my directory/"*.txt)
for f in "${FILES[@]}"
do
  echo "${f}"
done
```

In this case, `FILES` is an array of file names.  The parens surrounding the definition make it an array.  Note that the `*` is outside of quotes.  The construct `"${FILES[@]}"` is a special case: it will expand to a list of strings where each string is one of the file names.  File names with spaces or other difficult characters will be handled correctly.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you're passing paths like this around through functions, you need to ensure you quote the variable *on its own* rather than concatenating it as part of a larger string:

`for f in "$DIR"/*.txt` = fine  
`for f in "$DIR/*.txt"` = breaks

Answer (score 10):

While using arrays as shown by John1024 makes a lot more sense, here, you can also use the split+glob operator (leaving a scalar variable unquoted).

Since you only want the glob part of that operator, you need to disable the *split* part:

```
#! /bin/sh -
# that also works in any sh, so you don't even need to have or use bash

file_pattern="/home/john/my directory/*.txt"
# all uppercase variables should be reserved for environment variables

IFS='' # disable splitting

for f in $file_pattern # here we're not quoting the variable so
                       # we're invoking the split+glob operator.
do
  printf '%s\n' "$f" # avoid the non-reliable, non-portable "echo"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to leave only the wildcard characters outside of quotes.
Something like:
 for a in "files with spaces"*".txt"
 do
   processing
  done
If the wildcards themselves expand to spaces, then you'll need t use a file per line approach, like use ls -l to generate the list of files and use bash read to get each file.

Answer (score 1):

Single line based solution, (to run in Terminal):
`/usr/bin/find "./" -not -type d -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.txt" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' f ; do { echo "${f}"; }; done; unset f;`

for your/OP's case, change the `"./"` into `"/home/john/my directory/"`

To use in a script file:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/find "./" -not -type d -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.txt" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' f ; do {
    echo "${f}";
    # your other commands/codes, etc
};
done;
unset f;
```

Above functionality can be achieved in this (recommended) way too:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' f ; do {
    echo "${f}";
    # your other commands/codes, etc
};
done < <(/usr/bin/find "./" -not -type d -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.txt" -print0);
unset f;
```

Brief/Short DESCRIPTION:

**•** `"./"` : this is the current directory. specify a directory path.
**•** `-not -type d` : here the `-not` is configuring it to skip the next mentioned type, & next mentioned `-type` is `d` = directories, so it will skip directories. Use `f` instead of `d` to skip files. Use `l` instead of `d` to skip symlink-files.
**•** `-maxdepth 1` : is configuring it to find files within current (aka: one) directory level only. To find file inside each & first sub-directory level, set maxdepth to 2. If -maxdepth not used, then it will search recursively (inside sub-directories), etc.
**•** `-iname "*.jpg"` : here the `-iname` is configuring it to find files and ignore (upper/lower)-case in filename/extension. The `-name` does not ignore case. The `-lname` finds symlinks. etc.
**•** `-print0` : it prints pathname of current file to standard output, followed by an ASCII NUL character (character code 0), which we will later detect by using the `read` in `while`.
**•** `IFS=` : here its used in case a filename ends with a space. We are using NUL / `''` / `\0` with IFS to detect each found filename. As "[find](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html)" is configured to separate them with `\0` which is produced by `-print0`.
**•** `read -r -d $'\0' fileName` : the `$'\0'` is `''` / NUL . The `-r` was used in case a file name has a backslash.
  **•** [read](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins) [-ers] [-a aname] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars] [-p prompt] [-t timeout] [-u fd] [name ...] [...]
    -r     Backslash does not act as an escape character.  The backslash is considered to be part of the line.  In  particular,  a  backslash-newline pair may not be used as a line continuation.
**•** `done < <(...)` : Process-Substitution used here to send/pipe output of "find" into the "read" of "while"-loop. More info: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html , https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst , https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#PROCESS-SUB , https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#PSUBP

---

In other answer by @John1024, he has shown great bash-based solution, that does not use the "find", an external utility.
"find" is very effective & fast, i prefer it when there is too many files to handle.

in @John1024's solution it will print out the matching-rule line when there is no file in the directory, so below `[ ! -e "${f}" ]...` line is used to skip that,
here is single-line solution to use in Terminal directly:
`DIR="/home/john/my directory/" ; for f in "$DIR"*.txt ; do { [ ! -e "${f}" ] && continue; echo "${f}"; }; done; unset DIR;`

Here is a script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/home/john/my directory/";
for f in "$DIR"*.txt ; do {
    [ ! -e "${f}" ] && continue;
    echo "${f}";
    # your codes/commands, etc
};
done;
unset DIR;
```

Note: if the directory in DIR has `"/"` slash (directory indicator) at-end, then in matching-rule, again using the `"/"` is not necessary,
Or, do opposite: in DIR do not use the `"/"` at-end and so use it in matching-rule `"$DIR"/*.txt`

---

That extra checking by using the `[ ! -e "${f}" ]...` code can be avoided, if below **shell-option** (aka: "[shopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html)") is used or enabled:
`shopt -s nullglob`

If a shopt state was changed by a script, then in other bash based script program it creates unexpected/unanticipated problems.

To have consistent behavior across all scripts that uses bash, bash-shell-option's state should be recorded/saved inside your script, and once you're done using your primary functions in your script, then that shell-option should be set back to previous settings.

We use backtick (aka: grave-accent, aka: backquote) `` `...` `` [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) (for internal bash-command codes, etc), to not-spawn a new sub-shell, retain literal meaning of backslash, for wider support (aka: portability), etc, As backtick based internal bash-commands, etc can be often executed in same shell as the script, etc, And so it is little-bit faster & better, and also better for the purpose we are handling here.  If you prefer `$(...)` command-substitution then use that, anyone have freedom & right to choose what they prefer, avoid, etc.  More info: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9453635/3553808).

So above script is again shown, & this time with previous settings of a shopt restored, before ending the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/home/john/my directory/";

ub="/usr/bin";

# shopt = shell-option(s).
# Setting-up "previous-nullglob" state to "enabled"/"on"/"1":
p_nullglob=1;
# The "shopt -s" command output shows list of enabled shopt list, so if 
# nullglob is NOT set to ON/enabled, then setting "previous_nullglob" as 0
[ "`shopt -s | ${ub}/grep nullglob`" == "" ] && p_nullglob=0;
# Enabling shell-options "nullglob":
shopt -s nullglob;

# previous code, but without the extra checking [ ! -e "${f}" ]... line:
for f in "$DIR"*.txt ; do {
    echo "${f}";
    # your codes/commands, etc
};
done;

# As we have utilized enabled nullglob shopt, its now in enabled state,
# so if previously it was disabled only-then we will disable it:
[ "$p_nullglob" -eq "0" ] && shopt -u nullglob;

unset DIR;
unset p_nullglob ub;
```

Output of `shopt -p shoptName` (for example: `shopt -p dotglob`) can be
either, this: `shopt -u shoptName` (the `u` is `unset`/disabled/off/`0`)
or, this: `shopt -s shoptName` (the `s` is `set`/enabled/on/`1`)
The position of the letter `"s"` or `"u"` is always at `7` (because, in bash, a string's letter position begins from `0`, that is, the 1st letter of a string is at position `0`)
We can obtain this `"u"` or `"s"` and store it in a variable, so that we can use it to restore previous state.
And if we apply this (mentioned in above) way to save/restore shopt state, then we can avoid using external tool `"grep"`.

To view `"txt"` file that begins with `"."`, that is, to view hidden `"txt"` file, we need to enable `"dotglob"` shopt.

So this time in below, `"dotglob"` is included & enabled to show HIDDEN `"txt"` files:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/home/john/my directory/";

p_nullglob="u";
pSS="`shopt -p nullglob`";
[ "${pSS:7:1}" == "s" ] && p_nullglob="s";

p_dotglob="u";
pSS="`shopt -p dotglob`";
[ "${pSS:7:1}" == "s" ] && p_dotglob="s";

shopt -s nullglob dotglob;

for f in "$DIR"*.txt ; do {
    echo "${f}";
    # your codes/commands, etc
};
done;

[ "$p_nullglob" == "u" ] && shopt -u nullglob;
[ "$p_dotglob" == "u" ] && shopt -u dotglob;

unset DIR;
unset p_nullglob p_dotglob pSS;
```

There are more simple way to save/restore shopt option/value.
[Isaac](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/232326/isaac) posted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/310963/367237), how to save+restore Env/Shopt variable/option state/value.

Saving shopt state of "nullglob":
  `` p_nullglob="`shopt -p nullglob`"; ``
  `... # your primary-function codes/commands, etc lines`
Restoring back previous shopt state of "nullglob", before exiting script:
  `eval "$p_nullglob" ;`

Multiple shopt states can be saved this way:
  `` p_multipleShopt="`shopt -p nullglob dotglob`"; ``
and restore process is same as before:
  `eval "$p_multipleShopt" ;`

Save ALL shopt states this way:
  `` p_allShopt="`shopt -p`"; ``
and restore process is same as before:
  `eval "$p_allShopt" ;`

So here is another bash based solution:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/home/john/my directory/";

p_allShopt="`shopt -p`";
shopt -s nullglob dotglob;

for f in "$DIR"*.txt ; do {
    echo "${f}";
    # your codes/commands, etc
};
done;

eval "$p_allShopt" ;

unset DIR p_allShopt;
```

Using `eval` is safe in above, as the variable `"$p_allShopt"` is not holding a data provided by a user or a data thats not-sanitized, That var is holding output of bash internal command `shopt`.
If you still want to avoid `eval` then use below solution:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/home/john/my directory/";

p_allShopt="`shopt -p`";
shopt -s nullglob dotglob;

for f in "$DIR"*.txt ; do {
    echo "${f}";
    # your codes/commands, etc
};
done;

while IFS= read -a oneLine ; do {
    ${oneLine} ;
};
done < <(echo "$p_allShopt") ;

unset DIR p_allShopt oneLine;
```

Few (other) notable & related [SHOPT](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) that may be useful, are:

- nocaseglob : If set, Bash matches filenames in a case-insensitive fashion when performing filename expansion.
- nocasematch : If set, Bash matches patterns in a case-insensitive fashion when performing matching while executing `case` or `[[` conditional commands, when performing pattern substitution word expansions, or when filtering possible completions as part of programmable completion.
- dotglob : If set, Bash includes filenames beginning with a `‘.’` in the results of filename expansion. The filenames `‘.’` and `‘..’` must always be matched explicitly, even if dotglob is set.
- nullglob : If set, Bash allows filename patterns which match no files to expand to a null string, rather than themselves.
- extglob : If set, the extended pattern matching features described above (see [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching)) are enabled.
- globstar : If set, the pattern `‘**’` used in a filename expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by a `‘/’`, only directories and subdirectories match.

Answer (score -1):

When you want to process on set of files, you consider , at their name may be space or other scape code will be there, So before start your process such as `for loop` or `find command` set the `IFS bash env variable` to :

```
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
```