# How to save & restore all shell options including errexit

Tags: bash, shell

I have read through many questions on various stack exchange sites and unix help forums on how to modify shell options and then restore them -
 the most comprehensive one I found on here is at [How to "undo" a `set -x`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310957/how-to-undo-a-set-x)

The [received wisdom](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/310963/52838) seems to be to either save off the result of `set +o` or `shopt -po` and then `eval` it later to restore the previous settings.

However, in my own testing with bash 3.x and 4.x, the `errexit` option does not get saved correctly when doing command substitution.

Here is an example script to show the issue:

```
set -o errexit
set -o nounset
echo "LOCAL SETTINGS:"
set +o
OLDOPTS=$(set +o)
echo
echo "SAVED SETTINGS:"
echo "$OLDOPTS"
```

And output (I trimmed out some of the irrelevant variables):

```
LOCAL SETTINGS:
set -o errexit
set -o nounset

SAVED SETTINGS:
set +o errexit
set -o nounset
```

This seems extremely dangerous. Most scripts I write depend on `errexit` to halt execution if any commands fail. I just located a bug in one of my scripts caused by this, where the function that was supposed to restore `errexit` at the end wound up overriding it, setting it back to the default of *off* for the duration of the script.

What I'd like to be able to do is write functions that can set options as needed and then restore *all* the options properly before exiting. But it seems as if in the subshell invoked by the command substitution, `errexit` is not inherited.

I'm at a loss for how to save off the result of `set +o` without using command substitution or jumping through FIFO hoops. I can read from `$SHELLOPTS` but it is not writable or in `eval`-able format.

I know one alternative is to use a [subshell function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12179705/350761), but that introduces a lot of headaches for being able to log output as well as pass back multiple variables.

Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532904/bash-subshell-errexit-semantics (seems there is a workaround for bash 4.4 and up but I'd rather have a portable solution)

Comment: This doesn't restore bash `shopt` set options (like nullglob).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're doing should work. But bash turns off the `errexit` option in command substitutions, so it preserves all the options except this one. This is specific to bash and specific to the `errexit` option. Bash does preserve `errexit` when running in POSIX mode. Since bash 4.4, bash also doesn't clear `errexit` in a command substitution if `shopt -s inherit_errexit` is in effect.

Since the option is turned off before any code runs inside the command substitution, you have to check it outside.

```
OLDOPTS=$(set +o)
case $- in
  *e*) OLDOPTS="$OLDOPTS; set -e";;
  *) OLDOPTS="$OLDOPTS; set +e";;
esac
```

If you don't like this complexity, use zsh instead.

```
setopt local_options
```

Comment: Note that `bash4.4` now has `local -` (à la `ash`) as an equivalent to `zsh`'s `setopt localoptions` (or what ksh88 does by default)

Comment: See also `shopt -s lastpipe; set +o | IFS= read -rd '' OLDOPTS || :` (the two sets of options is another of `bash`'s idiosyncrasies).

Comment: Simpler: `OLDOPTS="$(set +o); set -$-"`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Where can I find docs on `local -`?

Comment: @user232326 Error `/bin/sh: set: line 582: illegal option -s` when running `set -xse`.

Answer (score 3):

After trying old of the above on alpine 3.6, I've now taken the following much simpler approach:

```
OLDOPTS="$(set +o); set -${-//c}"
set -euf -o pipefail

... my stuff

# restore original options
set +vx; eval "${OLDOPTS}"
```

as per documentation, "$-" holds the list of currently active options. Seems to work great, am I missing anything?

Comment: @Isaac I use 'set +euf' because $- only contains the list of *active* options. i.e. when resetting I first deactivate everything and then reactivate only the list of previously active options (I choose 'euf' because those are the only options I usually modify - for general purpose use it probably should contain the full list of possible options). 

Good point about 'set +vx', I modified the example above accordingly

Comment: that may work for errexit but not e.g. for bounds checking or globbing (`set -uf`)

Comment: @Isaac I stand corrected. I don't know what I did wrong. Thanks a tons for your help! Also good to see that you ran into and solved the -c flag problem - I wish I had seen your comment earlier ;)

Comment: I updated above solution based on @Isaac 's feedback

Answer (score 1):

`errexit` is propagated into process substitutions.

```
set -e

# Backup restore commands into an array
declare -a OPTS
readarray -t OPTS < <(shopt -po)

set +e

# Restore options
declare cmd
for cmd in "${OPTS[@]}"; do
    eval "$cmd"
done
```

Check:

```
$  shopt -po errexit
set -o errexit
```

Bash version:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to append the `errexit` setting to `OLDOPTS`:

```
OLDOPTS="$(set +o)"
[ "${BASH_VERSION:+x}" ] && shopt -qo errexit && OLDOPTS+=";set -e" || true
```

Done.

Comment: See also `[[ -o errexit ]]` (ksh/bash/zsh) and `[ -o errexit ]` (bash/ksh/yash)

Comment: The `shopt` is a valid command for bash, there is no meaningful reason to avoid it (I is only a matter of your personal preference of how answers should be written). Not a meaningful change. @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: Solution is not working in `/bin/sh`.