# loop on file with specific extension in a child folder shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, wildcards

I have a script on my mac where I'm trying to loop on the txt files inside a subfolder of my current location. This is `myscript.sh`:

```
cd /Users/Desktop/
for entry in $(pwd)/txt/*.txt 
do 
echo $entry
done
```

this prints a string of the path including `*txt` in it like `/Users/Desktop/txt/*.txt` I want to loop on the .txt files so I expect the `echo $entry` to print the names of the txt files but instead it prints `/Users/Desktop/txt/*.txt`

Comment: @Kusalananda I've updated my question.

Comment: for entry in $(pwd)/txt/*.txt; do echo $(pwd)/txt/${entry}; done

Comment: for mac.. check this post http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156534/bash-script-error-with-strings-with-paths-that-have-spaces-and-wildcards

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31797856/loop-through-files-in-mac-terminal

Comment: As an aside, you should use double quotes in `echo "$entry"`.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you give the shell a globbing pattern that doesn't match any file names, the globbing pattern will not be expanded.  In your case, this means that the `echo` in the loop outputs the pattern itself.

Alternative implementation of your script:

```
cd /Users/Desktop || exit 1

for entry in txt/*.txt; do 
    test -e "$entry" && echo "$entry"
done
```

This implementation will exit with a non-zero exit code if the `cd` fails. It will then *not* use `pwd` since it's unnecessary. It will get a list of names matching the pattern and will iterate over these. In each iteration, it tests to make sure there is actually something in the filesystem that has that name before outputting the name to standard output.

If you want the `echo` inside the lop to output the full path of the files, use `echo "/Users/Desktop/$entry"`, or even better:

```
dir="/Users/Desktop"
cd "$dir" || exit 1

for entry in txt/*.txt; do 
    test -e "$entry" && printf '%s/%s\n' "$dir" "$entry"
done
```

Comment: thanks, but why it doesn't match? although the path is correct and there are some txt files in it?

Comment: If you had files with an `.txt` suffix in the `txt` directory of your current working directory, then the paths of those files would be shown. The current working directory (returned by `pwd`) is the directory where you're currently at, not where the script lives.

Comment: I've updated my question as in the beginning of the script I did `cd` but the echo prints the correct directory, so I'm not sure why it's not working?

Comment: That's what `pwd` does.  The shell will resolve relative paths from the script's current directory anyway so `$(pwd)/` should just be replaced with nothing.  Or better yet take out the `cd` before the loop and just say `for entry in /Users/Desktop/txt/*.txt` (if you really genuinely have a directory named like that -- aren't you missing the user's account name?)